# Where can I learn about holograms?

Tags: resource-recommendations, hologram

I want to learn about [holograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holography). I have zero knowledge of how they work. How can I start? I tried using Google but I cannot decide where to and how to start. Can you suggest any good sites for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to learn about holograms and how they work depends on your background.  The book, "Optical Holography" by Collier, Burkhardt and Lin is for readers with a good math background, but a diligent reader can get a huge amount of information by reading between the equations.  That was my holography bible "back in the day".  The book, "Holography Handbook" by Fred Untersehr, was a standard for artists and hobbyists getting into holography back in the 1970's and 1980's; it had a few unimportant technical errors.  There is a hologram-making kit you can get on Amazon for something over $100, made by Liti Holo. For a similar price you can get hologram-making kits from [Integraf](https://www.integraf.com/shop/hologram-kits). Note: you definitely do not need a technical background to learn about how holograms work and how they are made.  You can find plenty of explanations online, both written and in video form; and probably the kit would give you at least a great intuitive grasp of the subject.